# resume cordova app running in background : phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Introduction**

Its hosted app built under phonegap tech. I am stuck in the situation when application is minimized, and need to resume when receive call in app (twilio functionality).

I have tried

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app

when calling cordova.backgroundapp.show() (cordova-plugin-background-app), application is now open but there is a problem because application is kind of restarting on resume.

If someone can help, i will be thankful. Thanks for your time.